# Showing Google Maps using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, google-maps

Do you know how we can show Google Maps as a base map in ArcObject stand alone map?

For example is there any WMS address from Google Maps that we can use it to connect to it or something like that?

I have used open layers before and it has ability to set Google Maps as base map... But I want to use Google Maps in my stand alone application without using GeoServer and ...

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This question overlaps with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72217/how-can-i-import-google-map-or-bing-map-to-my-application-using-arcengine which should probably have been closed as too broad because it was really asking two questions (ArcObjects with Google Maps?, and ArcObjects with Bing Maps?) so I am going to edit that question to take Google Maps out of it.

Comment: Google maps standard doesn't play nice with ArcMap. To get Google maps in ArcMap I believe one must purchase a Google Maps Pro license. You can have a look at this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23284/how-to-integrate-openlayers-and-arcgis-server but it probably wont help because openlayers will render to a web page but probably not to the ArcMap drawing canvas. Check out this one http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a8895908f98d4334b401de9b6d08e847 that one may help.

Comment: Be warned that the Add-in on that link has a **lot of bugs** and users are complaining about it. If you are game you can render google maps to a bitmap and display it that way - it will work but slow down refreshes as you need to pause the display while rendering then draw the bitmap.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Hi my friend.So there is not any good way to do this..thank you so much

Comment: I haven't seen one but haven't been looking. Google just isn't accurate enough for our purposes. I believe it should be technically feasible like the OpenLayers Plugin for QGIS. There was a good plugin in VBA that I used to pan a web page at the same time as ArcMap - that's as close as I got.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson for my aim I don't care about accuracy,I just want to use a base map for it..I think I should try using Openlayers in my application and easily show different maps to end-user it would be the best solution.

Comment: I will be watching with interest to see if someone knows how to do this. Others in my organization either don't care about accuracy so much or would prefer that ArcMap exactly matches Google Earth; temporal differences between Google Earth and purchased Orthophotography have been the cause of much concern previously and it would be nice to not have to deal with that!!!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Do you ever worked with google map engine?last night I read about it somewhere that It gives a wms address.I looked for it but couldn't find any wms address or something like that.

Comment: No, I've not used Google Engine.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I'll let you know if it is possible to use google map engine for this aim ..Thanks for your time and helps